# Fader Ticker JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ticker

This (lovely) little script I wrote should gently fade through each element in a list `<li></li>`. But nothing happens at all. What's wrong.

```
<div id="twitnews" style="padding-left:20px; line-height:20px; float:left;">
        <?php getFeed("http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=golf+berkshire"); ?>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fader() {

$(element).fadeIn(300, function(){
    $(element).delay(3000).fadeOut(300) });

        var element = $(element).next();

        fader();

}
$('#twitnews').children().hide();

var element = $('#twitnews').children().first();
fader();
        </script>
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: looks like your function runs forever

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in the original code, selectors were incorrect, global variables are not used correctly and this is perfect for a plugin demonstration.

```
(function($){
// Make it a plugin
$.fn.twicker = function(settings) {
  // Default Variables
  var c = {time: 1300};
  // Override the variables with the settings if available.
  $.extend(c, settings);
  var $t = $(this);
  // If we find a ul, means we passed the container (a div that contains a ul)
  if($('ul', $t).length == 1) {
      $tw = $t;
      $t = $('li', $t).first();
  }

  // Do the animation.
  $t.delay(c.time).fadeIn(c.time, function() {
    // If there's a next sibling, do next.
    if($t.next().length != 0) {
        $t.next().twicker();
        $t.next().fadeOut();

    // If there's no sibling, it means we're at the end. Go back to first.
    } else {
        $tw.first().twicker();
        $t.first().fadeOut();
    }
    $t.fadeOut(c.time);
  });

};

})(jQuery);

$('#twitnews').twicker({time:2000});
```

You can view this live on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/NyKeF/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much. It's very similar to what I have come up with however I believe mine to be simpler. I'll post it here. Let me know what you think of it.

Comment: This is very simple; but the key part is: it's reusable. If you want strip the plugin functionality and turn it into a function, it'll look like less code but won't be reusable on the long run.   **Remember** the GOAL of all developers is: DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Answer (score -1):

Try passing `element` to `fader()`.

```
fader(element);
```

at the end of your script.

Also include `element` when you define `fader()`

```
function fader(element){
    //the rest of your function code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why your script doesn't work, but I suggest you take a little different approach. Replace all your JS code with:

```
$('#twitnews').children().each(function(){
  $(this).fadeIn(300, function() {
    $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
  });
});
```

Note: I have only rearranged your code to get rid of global vars, weird element traversing and recursive calls. I did not touch the animation - but you should be able to find the bugs very easily with the new code.

Comment: That would fade all of them out together

Comment: Of course - that is what your original script does too. What exactly were you trying to accomplish? I merely cleaned up your script.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a very simple solution. The only problem is the use of the if function to determine if this is the last li is non functional. Perhaps someone knows what's wrong with it.

```
 $('#twitnews li').hide();
    $('#twitnews li').first().fadeIn(300, function fade(){

        var visel = $('#twitnews li:visible');

        if((visel).is($('#twitnews li:last'))) {
            var nextel =  $('#twitnews li').first();
        }
        else {
        var nextel = $(visel).next();
        }


        $(visel).delay(3000).fadeOut(300, function(){

            $(nextel).fadeIn(300, function(){fade()});

            });

        });
```

Comment: Don't answer your own question. If you need to clarify something, edit your original question.